Weird graph product
Let $G = (V,E_G)$ and $H=(V,E_H)$ be two graphs on the same set of nodes. Let $H = (V \times V, E_H)$, where $E_H = \{\{(a,b),(c,d)\} | \{a,d\} \in E_G \vee \{b,c\} \in E_H \}$.
So it is almost like a Cartesian sum of graphs but has this weird order swap.
Has anyone seen something like it? I'm mostly interested in understanding chromatic number of such products.

I dont fully understand what $H$ is. The edge-relation might not be symmetric. Is $H$ only a directed graph or do we also want to include the edges ${a,d}\in E_ H...$?
